# grunt clean fail unable to delete ".tmp" file (EPERM, operation not permitted)

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

When I built a yeoman angular app, when I run it for the first time it works fine using `grunt serve` but when i run it the second time an error from `grunt clean task` as following:

```
Cleaning .tmp...ERROR
Warning: Unable to delete ".tmp" file (EPERM, operation not permitted '...\.tmp'). Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

When I delete the .tmp folder manually the app runs without errors.

I searched the net and here but I couldn't find a convincing answer.

Please advice,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by updating the version of the rimraf node module inside of grunt-contrib-clean.

```
$ cd .\node_modules\grunt-contrib-clean 
$ npm install rimraf@2.2.8
```

This looks like the commit in rimraf that fixed the issue: https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf/commit/1b612ed9370b5a3d0de9bb0ba1a32ea1dc8edba1

Comment: thanx it was solved, I'll install it globally so I'll not face this issue with new projects

Answer (score 2):

Was having a similar issue running "grunt build" from Mac.  Issue turned out to be file permissions, to fix I did "sudo chmod -R  ." on the root directory and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if any explorer of the directory you are trying to delete is open. If so, close the explorer and clean.
2. Try this simple solution(Sometimes problem might be due to empty folder).
    It works for me :

```js
clean : {
  dist : ['./dist'+'/**/*.*']
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chgrp -R username .tmp
sudo chown -R username .tmp
```